# Address Book C# GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface, special-folders

Alright so I've decided to create my first GUI Address book and I've been following a tutorial on Youtube that allows us to create an Address Book that is suppose to store the information entered into the text boxes as an xml but I've been having trouble.

So when the form loads, it's suppose to check for a folder named "Address Book" and if it's not there, create it. Then check if a document is in there, if not, it creates it. But for some reason the folder does not get created, even though it doesn't exist, same with the xml file.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    if(!Directory.Exists(path + "\\Address Book"))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\Address Book");
    if (!File.Exists(path + "\\Address Book\\settings.xml"))
        {
            XmlTextWriter xW = new XmlTextWriter(path + "\\Address Book\\settings.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            xW.WriteStartElement("People");
            xW.WriteEndElement();
            xW.Close();
        }
```

Can anyone point out my mistake? The original path was SpecialFolder.ApplicationData but I wanted to use desktop because looking for the folder would be a click away.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: You might also want to look into [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sounds pretty much like `Read/Write` permission access issue.

Do not use `Desktop` like  file/directory write destination, but use folders where your OS `User`, so the application too, is *guranteed* to have relative permissions. So those folders which you saw in tutorial. Especially latest `WinOS` es are very rigid on this kind of stuff.

If it frustraits you, to navigate to those folders every time, create a `link` to that folder on your `Desktop`. Fast and easy.

Comment: So create a folder inside of the Public folder?

Comment: Oh wait....I think I know what the problem is...let me check...

Comment: Oh god...I am so stupid! I am using a virtual version of Visual Studio 2010 and the reason the files weren't creating on my desktop is because I was creating them on the virtual desktop and search for them on my computer. So sorry everyone!

Comment: @user1580598: even if you're able to do that on your machine, for some security luck, do not do that. Do not write code that will fail (for sure) on client machine with a slightly different configuration then yours. Good luck.